# Why my bin/magento setup:upgrade is really slow?

Tags: magento2, php, performance, cli

Running this command seems incredibly slow taking around half an hour+. I feel like it didn't always take this long and am wondering if this is normal and if not what can cause this?

This is a very basic almost default Magento 2 installation on a dedicated server with **NGINX PHP7 MYSQL**. I have been trying to write some basic modules however this is really slowing me down.

Comment: Do you see a start of an output when you run this command?
Any logs inside Magento log or Nginx / PHP logs?

Comment: I cannot see any errors in Magento Logs or NGINX logs. The output looks normal from the command i get a list of Modules and it just ticks through really slow.

Comment: On Magento DevBox (2GB memory) M2.1.3, it runs in less than 1 minute.

Comment: Yeah when i first run it earlier today it took like 10 seconds. Moments later when i ran it again it has taken nearly an hour. I might try again see what happens.

Comment: Have you develop an updater or something that can take some time?

Comment: Ok it seems fine for now strange.

Comment: This is intermitent for me and im feeling my situation may have been server related as migrating has led to be not experiencing this problem since.

Answer (score 6):

We have the same experience. 
After **"DDL cache cleared successfully"** you can wait a long time for the next step.

We found out that we can increase the speed by moving the folder `pub/media/catalog` to `temp/media/catalog` before running `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: Did anyone find the solution for slowness of setup:upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. It seems issue is due to partial or incomplete di compile execution. I cleared cache and generated folder and re run command.